# ultralytics yolov5 rtsp stream Windows 10 : cannot open videoCapture

Tags: python, rtsp, yolov5

I am trying yo run inferences with detect.py from ultralytics yolov5 (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5).

I created a Python environment under Windows 10, with python 3.9 and installed the requirements.txt.

I checked opencv installation and have FFMPEG set to YES.

I can run inferences on my webcam using --source 0.

However, I cannot run inferences on a rtsp stream, which works on VLC for example (no problem with the rtsp link).

The error is from utils/datasets.py, line 309 : opencv cannot open the VideoCapture.

I tried adding the backend like this : `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtst_path, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)`.
I also tried to add this line before opening the cap : `os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"`

None of this works. I guess it comes from my environment. Any help ?

Environment details :

```
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - ca-certificates=2021.10.26=haa95532_2
  - certifi=2021.10.8=py39haa95532_0
  - cudatoolkit=10.2.89=h74a9793_1
  - freetype=2.10.4=hd328e21_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=haa95532_3556
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - libpng=1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
  - libtiff=4.2.0=hd0e1b90_0
  - libuv=1.40.0=he774522_0
  - libwebp=1.2.0=h2bbff1b_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h2bbff1b_1
  - mkl=2021.4.0=haa95532_640
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py39h2bbff1b_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py39h277e83a_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py39hf11a4ad_0
  - ninja=1.10.2=py39h559b2a2_3
  - numpy=1.21.2=py39hfca59bb_0
  - numpy-base=1.21.2=py39h0829f74_0
  - olefile=0.46=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - openssl=1.1.1l=h2bbff1b_0
  - pillow=8.4.0=py39hd45dc43_0
  - pip=21.2.4=py39haa95532_0
  - python=3.9.7=h6244533_1
  - pytorch=1.9.0=py3.9_cuda10.2_cudnn7_0
  - pytorch-mutex=1.0=cuda
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py39haa95532_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sqlite=3.37.0=h2bbff1b_0
  - tk=8.6.11=h2bbff1b_0
  - torchaudio=0.9.0=py39
  - torchvision=0.10.0=py39_cu102
  - typing_extensions=3.10.0.2=pyh06a4308_0
  - tzdata=2021e=hda174b7_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py39haa95532_2
  - xz=5.2.5=h62dcd97_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h8cc25b3_4
  - zstd=1.4.9=h19a0ad4_0
  - pip:
    - absl-py==1.0.0
    - cachetools==4.2.4
    - charset-normalizer==2.0.10
    - colorama==0.4.4
    - cycler==0.11.0
    - fonttools==4.28.5
    - google-auth==2.3.3
    - google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
    - grpcio==1.43.0
    - idna==3.3
    - importlib-metadata==4.10.0
    - kiwisolver==1.3.2
    - markdown==3.3.6
    - matplotlib==3.5.1
    - oauthlib==3.1.1
    - opencv-python==4.5.5.62
    - packaging==21.3
    - pandas==1.3.5
    - protobuf==3.19.3
    - pyasn1==0.4.8
    - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
    - pyparsing==3.0.6
    - python-dateutil==2.8.2
    - pytz==2021.3
    - pyyaml==6.0
    - requests==2.27.1
    - requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
    - rsa==4.8
    - scipy==1.7.3
    - seaborn==0.11.2
    - tensorboard==2.7.0
    - tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
    - tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
    - thop==0.0.31-2005241907
    - tqdm==4.62.3
    - urllib3==1.26.8
    - werkzeug==2.0.2
    - zipp==3.7.0
```

cv2.getBuildInformation() output :

```
  Version control:               4.5.5

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-12-28T06:21:01Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.22.1
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24245.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.6/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.6/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.6.8/x64/python.exe (ver 3.6.8)
    Libraries:                   C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.6.8/x64/libs/python36.lib (ver 3.6.8)
    numpy:                       C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.6.8/x64/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/2.7.18/x64/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.312-7/x64/include C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.312-7/x64/include/win32 C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/8.0.312-7/x64/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.6/cmake-install
```